# SSRS function for colour change

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

I have a report in SSRS 2012 that uses calendar dates across the top and below shows how many hours have been taken off by staff, in the data set that returns the content of the report, it also lists at what status the holiday is at, whether rejected, accpeted, pending, what I want to do is 2 checks at the same time when changing the background colour to a cell, check that there is a number of hours to take off and then to check what status those hours are at.

The cell expression would check if there is a value first, then check what status that value is at and then colour code the cell with the hours as required, I dont want to show the Status in the report.

Can anyone help, I can supply more details but currently out of the office at the moment and using phone.

Thanks Phil

Answer (score 1):

After some Googling and testing I have found my answer as shown below

```
=IIf(Fields!Hours.Value > 0 And Fields!Stauts.Value="Approved", "GREEN", "No Color")
```

Comment: You should mark this as the accepted answer (yes, you can do this even when you answer your own question) as that will assist future people searching for this solution.

Comment: Thanks Chris, will Mark it now, been a while since I have been on this site, thanks for reminder!!  Apparently cant accept my answer till tomorrow but will do so then!!